# Header and Footer from second PDF page using jspdf-html2canvas npm library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, pdf-generation, jspdf, html2canvas

I am using jspdf-html2canvas npm library to generate pdf. I am able to generate pdf but the issue is that I want to add header and footer all the pages except first page. I am able to set header and footer using `pdf.text` and top margin (I've added padding top and bottom in `page2` html content) but I am not able to set margin bottom for the footer.

If I set margin to html2PDF itself then it will show margins to all the pages. So, how to set margins to all the pages except first page?

Below is my code to generate PDF;

```
import html2PDF from "jspdf-html2canvas";
const generatePDF = () => {
  var page = document.getElementsByClassName('page')[0] as HTMLElement;
  var page2 = document.getElementsByClassName('page')[1] as HTMLElement;
  if(page){
    html2PDF([page,page2],{
      jsPDF:{format:[375,200], unit:'px'},
      success: function(pdf){
        const pageCount = pdf.getNumberOfPages();   
        for (var i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) {
          if(i>=2){
            pdf.addImage('iVBORw0KGgoA....','png',(pdf.internal.pageSize.width / 2) - 30, 5,15,15);
            pdf.addFileToVFS('../../../../../../public/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf',"AAEAAAASAQA....");
            pdf.addFont('../../../../../../public/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf','Roboto','Medium');
            pdf.setFont('Roboto','Medium');
            pdf.setFontSize(5);
            pdf.setTextColor('#424242');
            /* Header */
            pdf.text(getHeaderLineOne(), (pdf.internal.pageSize.width / 2) - 10, 15);
            pdf.text(getHeaderLineTwo(), (pdf.internal.pageSize.width / 2), 25, {
              align: 'center'
            });
            /* Footer */
            pdf.text(getHeaderLineTwo(), pdf.internal.pageSize.width / 2, (pdf.internal.pageSize.height) - 10, {
              align: 'center'
            });                
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```